# ezpublish : want to get new comment and delete it

Tags: ezpublish

In an ezpublish extension i need to know when a new comment is created and to get all informations about it.

I have seen in a blog that an object can be get with this:

```
$currentNode = eZContentObjectTreeNode::fetch($nodeId);
```

but my question is, a comment is a ezContentObject?

And is it possible to delete a comment?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of building forums withe eZ Publish, and the answer to your question depends on which one you chose.

Let me fire a couple of questions, that should help us help **you** :

- Are you using a default, standard package like "eZ Website Interface" (aka ezwebin), or eZ Flow ?
- Is the 'ezcomments' extension enabled on your eZ Publish instance ? (you can check this frm the back-office, at the following URL : /setup/extensions )

Cheers,

Comment: i am using ezflow and not using ezcomments ;-)
in a extension i want to get the latest comment. My workflow is called when a comment is published but i don't get the comment, thanks

Comment: So you are already at the workflow level : good, we'll have more possibilities then. Make sure your workflow event is plugged-in on the publish/after trigger. In other words : your custom workflow event wil have the already-published object at disposal. What would you like to do then with the object ? (once you tell me I can update my reply above with a code example - code snippets are not handled properly in stackoverflow comments). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If your comments are handled as content objects (basically if you don't use eZ Comments), then  the latest comment might be retrieved in PHP using the *same* syntax that you usually use in templates (http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Modules/content/Fetch-functions/tree), for instance :

```php
$params = array( 'ClassFilterType' => 'include',
                 'ClassFilterArray' => array( 'comment' ),
                 'SortBy' => array( 'published', true ),
                 'Offset' => 0,
                 'Limit' => 1 );

$lastComment = eZContentObjectTreeNode::subTreeByNodeID( $params, 2 );
```

Note that you might need to change the class identifier to something different than *comment* (which is the default one when installing eZ Webin or eZ Flow) and the parent node_id from where you'll *browse* your content subtree (which in my example is **2**.

Then if you want to remove that content, you can take a piece of code in one of these module/views :

- content/removenode (defined in kernel/content/removenode.php)
- content/removeobject (defined in kernel/content/removeobject.php)

Take care when removing a content object from your content repository, there are several operations to complete :

- remove the location(s) (what we call the node(s) actually)
- remove the object
- clear the cache in some case

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on which extension you are using to handle your comments. Generic eZ Publish comments are handled as content. However, the new eZ Comments extension does not treat comments as content and are handled differently. To access eZ Comments you will have to take a look at the eZ Comments classes and module directories. That said, eZ Comments comes prepackaged with template handling, so you should be able to do everything you need to do at the template level.